# JavaScript Code Refactor and fadeIn Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am fairly new to Javascript and am looking for a advice on refactoring the code below to be more efficient.

The code does the following: 
1. 19 images fade-in with various delays
2. When a mouse hovers over one of the various images, an explanation of that image will appear in a div at the top of the screen.

Any help creating a new, much shorter, code that accomplishes the same thing would be extremely helpful, as 19 images currently require a ton of space for the JavaScript code and I would be surprised if there weren't a more elegant script to accomplish the same thing.

Also, I would like to add a fade-in to the div that appears at the top of the window, but have been unable to add it correctly.

Thank you for your time and help.

HTML Example

```
<div id="arch">
    <div class="fade-in two-seven">
        <img src="myimage" />
    </div>
</div>
<!--Fade In Image-->
<div id="arch-con">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<!--Top Screen div-->
<div id="bran">
    <div class="fade-in three-one">
        <img src="myimage" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bran-con">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<div id="code">
    <div class="fade-in three-nine">
        <img src="myimage" ALT="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="code-con">
    <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

CSS Example

```
#arch {
    left: 25%;
    top: 27%;
    width: 14%;
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
}
#arch:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
#arch-con {
    width: 30%;
    height: 12%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 18, 150, 0.81) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: none;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding: 11px;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 35%;
    text-align: center;
}
#arch-con p {
    color: white;
    font-size:120%
}
#bran {
    left: 44%;
    top: 27%;
    width: 18%;
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
}
#bran:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
#bran-con {
    width: 30%;
    height: 12%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 18, 150, 0.81) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: none;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding: 11px;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 35%;
    text-align: center;
}
#bran-con p {
    color: white;
    font-size:120%
}
#code {
    left: 66%;
    top: 27%;
    width: 14.5%;
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
}
#code:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
#code-con {
    width: 30%;
    height: 12%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 18, 150, 0.81) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: none;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding: 11px;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 35%;
    text-align: center;
}
#code-con p {
    color: white;
    font-size:120%
}
```

JavaScript Example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#arch").on("mouseenter", function () {
        $("#arch-con").show();
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        $("#arch-con").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bran").on("mouseenter", function () {
        $("#bran-con").show();
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        $("#bran-con").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#code").on("mouseenter", function () {
        $("#code-con").show();
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        $("#code-con").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you everybody so much for the answers - extremely helpful!

Comment: Why the down-vote, did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you need in a much more DRY fashion by using common classes:

```
<div id="arch" class="image-container">
    <div class="fade-in two-seven">
        <img src="myimage" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="arch-con" class="text-container">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div id="bran" class="image-container">
    <div class="fade-in three-one">
        <img src="myimage" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bran-con" class="text-container">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div id="code" class="image-container">
    <div class="fade-in three-nine">
        <img src="myimage" ALT="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="code-con" class="text-container">
    <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Then you can use the same function on all the elements with this class:

```
$(function() {
    $('.image-container').hover(function() {
        $(this).next('.text-container').toggle();
    });             
});
```

Also note that you can use the `hover()` event with `toggle()` to tidy the logic further.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jdp6fcqb/)

Comment: I feel silly for not using the image-container / text-container, as it is 20 times more manageable. Seeing that was a "duh" moment. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make a selector that matches all the elements, then you can use the `next` method to get to the `div` to show/hide:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#arch,#bran,#code").on("mouseenter", function() {
      $(this).next().show();
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
      $(this).next().hide();
  });

});
```

If you add a class to all the divs, then the selector gets shorter. You can also use that to reuse code in the CSS. Example assuming the class `expimg` and `expimg-con` on the pair of elements:

```
.expimg { height: auto; visibility: visible; position: absolute; }
.expimg:hover { transform: scale(1.05); }
.expimg-con { width: 30%; height: 12%; position: absolute; background: rgba(0, 18, 150, 0.81) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 4px solid #FFF; border-radius: 20px; display: none; line-height: 0px; padding: 11px; margin: 0px; left: 35%; text-align: center; }
.expimg-con p {color: white; font-size:120%}

#arch { left: 25%; top: 27%; width: 14%; }
#bran { left: 44%; top: 27%; width: 18%; }
#code { left: 66%; top: 27%; width: 14.5%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you only want to have one `document.ready()`. [According to the docs...](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute

So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('foo');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('bar');
});
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('foo');
    alert('bar');
});
```

.. It's not technically wrong to have multiple document ready statements, but you don't have a specific reason to, its a better rule of thumb to just use one.

Second, as an alternative to @Rory and @Guffa's correct answers, you can also accomplish the functionality you want through just using jQuery selectors..

**Example:**

```js
$('#foo, #bar, #baz').hover(function(){
  var tarElem = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + "-con";
  $(tarElem).toggle();
});
```

```css
.a{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: steelblue;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.b{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
    margin: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a" id="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="a" id="bar">Bar</div>
<div class="a" id="baz">Baz</div>
<div class="b" id="foo-con">Foo-con</div>
<div class="b" id="bar-con">Bar-con</div>
<div class="b" id="baz-con">Baz-con</div>
```

Comment: Great I got rid of the multiples, and of course, the code functions the same. Thanks!